# What settings must I change so that when add a contact on my mac, it will sync to my phone?

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud

Running Yosemite on a 2011 MBP and and iPhone 6.

A contact added to my phone will appear on my mac, but not vice versa.  How can I change this?

Comment: What internet Accounts are active on your devices, and what are the settings on those?

Comment: On the iPhone the relevant info will be under iCloud and / or "Mail, Contacts, Calendar"